# How to view Gradle source set paths?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am currently working on an Android project, which, for various legacy reasons, uses a non-standard Gradle layout. I'm trying to add a class which will have different implementations in different build flavors, but it's not being picked up by the compiler. The project uses `setRoot`, so the paths are partially auto-generated, and I suspect they may be wrong.

So my question is, how do I view the source set paths that Gradle is actually using? This seems like it would be simple, but neither the built-in help nor several hours of Googling have yielded any answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android plugin adds the task `sourceSets` that prints out all the source sets defined in the project.

You can run this from the command line:

```
gradle sourceSets
```

Or expand `Tasks->Android->sourceSets` in the Gradle panel of Android Studio

Comment: How does one use that inside a Gradle script? Please pardon my ignorance, as I'm still pretty new to Gradle development.

Comment: I'm guessing you're interested in inspecting source file list during compile? In which case you should probably extend the `compile` task. Updating my answer. aside: ignorance is why we all come to SO, no pardons necessary.

Comment: It runs, but I'm not seeing any output. The build just completes normally with that in.

Comment: Are you running `gradle compile`?

Comment: No, I wasn't. It's now outputting the 'This is executed first during the execution phase.' string, but still no path information.

Comment: Try adding the `doFirst` to `build` instead of `compile`? `task build {`

Comment: That outright won't run; I get a message that says "Cannot add task ':<project>:build' as a task with that name already exists."

Comment: Are you sure this solution is compatible with the Android plugin? I think I read somewhere that Android fiddles with the task structure a bit.

Comment: Nope, this is a generic gradle way to do it. So I looked up the android plugin, and apparently there is already a predefined task to do what you're asking.

Comment: Aha! That worked perfectly, although I had to update my Android plugin for it (which is why it didn't pop up in the help before). Thank you very much!